# Error with SQL update Statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to update something in a sql database, but every time it gives me an error ...

This is my code:

```
// UPDATE SQL
- (void)sqlId:(int)sqlId text:(NSString *)text time:(NSString *)time preis:(NSString *)preis
{
    [self openDb];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"UPDATE `webdesign` SET data='%@', time='%d', preis='%@' WHERE id='%d')",
                               text, [time intValue], preis, sqlId];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"updated");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    [self closeDb];

}
```

The console says:

```
2013-08-31 12:07:21.366 Webdesign[6519:a0b] database opened
2013-08-31 12:07:21.367 Webdesign[6519:a0b] Error
2013-08-31 12:07:21.367 Webdesign[6519:a0b] database closed
```

maybe it's a simple problem, but I can't find it.

Comment: You forget to create 

`sqlite3_stmt * statement = NULL;`

Comment: Check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. And when any function fails, call [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Answer (score 0):

without knowing the table structure of your SqLite3 database, it's not possible to provide you with a 100% correct answer, but I suspect the line

```
UPDATE `webdesign` SET data='%@', time='%d', preis='%@' WHERE id='%d')
```

to be erroneous. In fact, you put decimals between single quotes, you put the name of the table between single quotes, ...

I tend to use an NSLog to write out the created statement, and copy/paste that statement in my sqlite3 command line tool (or in Valentina Studio, which I use often) to check if the created statement is correct. This has saved me lots of time.

Kind regards,
PB

Answer (score 0):

DAMN I've found the error ...

```
@"UPDATE `webdesign` SET data='%@', time='%d', preis='%@' WHERE id='%d')"
```

The ")" is the mistake ! :D

always such a small error -.-